# autolayout centering uilabel on x-axis fit to content with uiimage follow on the left side

Tags: ios, uiimage, uilabel, autolayout

I have a `UILabel` which should be centered horizontally and the width should be set according to its content length. and on the left side of the `UILabel` an `UIImage` should be positioned which should be aligned to `UILabel`. if `UILabel` needs more space then it should push `UIImage` to the left, and if `UILabel` needs less space then it should pull `UIImage` toward x-center.

I had it without layout working fine, but has to use auto layout. I'm trying but i can't figured it out.

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-padding-[img(16)][lblUserName]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:@{@"padding":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:Padding]} views:displayViewDic];
```

is it possible with auto layout? so sometimes it will be like in number 1 and other times like number 2.

[image]

Comment: Using storyboards or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@"H:|-padding-[img(16)][lblUserName]-padding-|"
```

Here you're saying that the image has to be a  fixed distance from the superview's leading edge. That doesn't match your description.

You might just need to change it to

```
@"H:|-(>=padding)-[img(16)][lblUserName]-(>=padding)-|"
```

To allow some flexibility in the margins.

To center a view horizontally, you have to manually create the constraint:

```
[view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lblUserName
     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
     toItem:view 
     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
     multiplier:1.0 
     constant:0]];
```

You don't need to use sizeToFit or any other methods like that - an image view and a label will have an intrinsic content size based on the image or the text.

Because you have an inequality, you may need to force the label to be as narrow as possible to prevent stretching:

```
[lblUserName setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Comment: thank you for answering. how to center lblUserName with VFL? or should create another constraint which should center uilabel?

Comment: should still use sizetoFit with this constraint settings?

Answer (score 1):

Add a horizontal center constraint to the label. Just this, and a suitable y position constraint would keep the label in the center. It'd expand equally in both directions to accommodate the content.

Now, add a horizontal spacing constraint to the image view's trailing space and the label's leading space for the x position, a suitable constraint for the y position (align vertical center with the label, perhaps?) and suitable constraints/image/intrinsic size for the size.

Code:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[img(width)]-padding-[lblUserName]" options:0 metrics:@{@"width": 50, @"padding": 20} views:displayViewDic]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lblUserName attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:0 toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:0.0 constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: thanks for helping! it works now! i used partly your answer for centering :)

Comment: @HashmatKhalil You don't need to use inequalities. These two lines of code are all you need. Don't add extra constraints.